# How in app purchase deatils are maintained once user clicks on Clear cache in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

When I was testing inapp purchase a question struck my mind.Here it goes like, Do clear data for Google play app ,all the in app purchase details got erased from the Google play app.So My question is,if user accidentally cleared the data then what happens to his previously purchased plans?
Will android maintains the record of it some where else,so that it restores the stuff later point of time ?

Here is My use case.Let us say an app has subscription model.User opens and buys the subscription for say 7 days.So on 8th day he comes I should show him a purchase window,for that I need to query an information from play service.If user has already cleared the play service from where can I get SKU info ?

Comment: Although I have not down voted this question, I can only assume that it was because of the question content. This question is off-topic for StackOverflow because it is *not* about programming.

Comment: I explain My use case.Let us say an app has subscription model.User opens and buys the subscription for say 7 days.So on 8th day he comes I should show him a purchase window,for that I need to query an information from play service.If user has already cleared the play service from where can I get SKU info ? By keeping that in context I posted above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play stores your purchase information on Google servers, linked to your Google Account.  After you've re-authenticated with your Google Account, you can restore your previous purchases. Nothing special is really required from Android frameworks.